# How to reduce array of objects by value

Tags: arrays, date, object, reduce

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const array = [
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 13},
   { someDate: "2021-01-28T12:57:15.000", count: 12},
   { someDate: "2021-01-28T12:57:15.000", count: 10},
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 9},
   { someDate: "2021-02-07T10:32:37.000", count: 7},
   { someDate: "2021-02-07T10:32:37.000", count: 5},
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 4}
];
```

and I want to reduce objects by date if dates are the same and to get sum of counts for that date. This is the result I want to achieve

```
const array = [
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 26},
   { someDate: "2021-01-28T12:57:15.000", count: 22},
   { someDate: "2021-02-07T10:32:37.000", count: 12},
];
```

How can I achieve this? Any example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to keep track of the ones you have seen by `someDate` and then add up the count for that record.

```
const array = [
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 13},
   { someDate: "2021-01-28T12:57:15.000", count: 12},
   { someDate: "2021-01-28T12:57:15.000", count: 10},
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 9},
   { someDate: "2021-02-07T10:32:37.000", count: 7},
   { someDate: "2021-02-07T10:32:37.000", count: 5},
   { someDate: "2021-01-19T14:18:20.000", count: 4}
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, current) => {
   const {someDate, count} = current;
   
   const existing = acc.find(a => a.someDate === someDate);
   if (existing) {
      existing.count += count;
   } else {
      acc.push(current);
   }
   
   return acc;
}, []);
```